# razor page: how to retrieve bytearray from file (IFormCollection)

Tags: razor

After Post I get this IFormCOllection returned:

[image]

On it lies the picture I uploaded in the frontend.
I need to access this picture to upload it to our backend.

How would I be able to access the single bytes from the `data.File?`